# SQL command usage of in / or

Tags: sql, foxpro

I have an sql command similar to below one.

```
select * from table1 
where table1.col1 in (select columnA from table2 where table2.keyColumn=3) 
or table1.col2 in (select columnA from table2 where table2.keyColumn=3)
```

Its performance is really bad so how can I change this command? (pls note that the two sql commands in the paranthesis are exactly same.)

Comment: In this instance I'd suggest using a distinct with an inner join, let SQL know what you're after, and leave it to evaluate the performance.

Comment: Do you have an index on Table2 for ColumnA?

Comment: @DRapp In fact my subquery is as edited one. I have an index for `table2.keyColumn`, but not for `table2.ColumnA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select distinct t1.* from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 ON t1.col1 =t2.columnA OR t1.col2 = t2.columnA
```

Comment: 99% it will be a good solution, but in theory this request can be not equivalent to the original one in case if table1 has no primary key and contains row duplicates. In such case your result will loose these duplicates.

Comment: If table1 has no primary key and contains row duplicates, he's got a lot worse problems to deal with, as those conditions violate the relational model.

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select *
from table1
where table1.col1 in (select columnA from table2 and t2.keyColumn = 3) or
      table1.col2 in (select columnA from table2 and t2.keyColumn = 3);
```

Probably the best approach is to build an index on `table2(keyColumn, columnA)`.

It is also possible that `in` has poor performance characteristics.  So, you can try rewriting this as an `exists` query:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.columnA = t1.col1 and t2.keyColumn = 3) or
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.columnA = t2.col1 and t2.keyColumn = 3);
```

In this case, the appropriate index is `table2(columnA, keyColumn)`.

Comment: You don't need 2 separate exists.

Comment: @palindrom . . . You don't *need* two separate `exists`.  But for performance reasons, I think you want them.  They help to guarantee that the index will really be used.  I don't know if foxpro is smart enough to use an index when the condition is `or`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your answer. I tried but it changed slightly(change was ignorable in my case )

Comment: @palindrom I am getting 'error correlating fields' if I join the exists'. `... where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.columnA = t1.col1 or t2.columnA = t1.col2)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're doing this in VFP, use SYS(3054) to see how the query is being optimized and what part is not.

Comment: My database is foxpro but calling it from .net c#.

Comment: If you can get access to VFP, you can test the optimization to fine tune the query.

Answer (score 0):

Are the main query and subqueries fully Rushmore-optimisable?

Since the subqueries do not appear to be correlated (i.e. they don't refer to table1 then as long as everything is fully supported by indexes you should be fine.